# blender issue with manjaro

Tags: python, linux

I have installed blender on manjaro xfce and when I try to run blender in terminal it shows this error:
blender: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: did you try installing python 3 from the repo?

Comment: Blender should come with all the required libs. Please try to use the official build from the [Blender website](https://www.blender.org/download/), in case the issue is in the Manjaro repository.